# simple javascript google analytics event error, not sending to ga

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've got a button on my site that I want to track as an GA event. The javascript function is properly redirecting the user but the GA call is not showing anything in the real-time view of google analytics and have no idea why not. It is showing my visit in Google analytics (the only 1..) so it seems me, not trigging the event.

```
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-138599174-1');
</script>

<script>  
  function handleOutboundLinkClicks() {
    ga('send', 'event', {
      eventCategory: 'GVoteRSVP',
      eventAction: 'click',
      transport: 'beacon'
    });

    window.location.href = "URL";  
  }
</script>
```

BUTTON:

```
<a href="#" onClick="handleOutboundLinkClicks()" class="sqs-block-button-element--medium sqs-block-button-element" >
    REGISTER TODAY
</a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `gtag` to initialize Analytics, you need to use the same method to send events. In your code you are currently referring to `ga()` instead. Your function should look like this:

```
function handleOutboundLinkClicks() {
  gtag('event', 'click', {
    'event_category': 'GVoteRSVP'
  });

  window.location.href = "URL";

}
```

Generally, the event parameters can be passed like this:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

You can find further details in [this guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events). If you need to set the transport type to beacon, as it is used in your current code, you might want to read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data#specify_different_transport_mechanisms) as well.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.